# Method in Laravel to give a JSON response indicating whether the user may edit

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on creating code with a nice balance between concise and readable.
How would you improve this Laravel code block to make it more compact and readable?

```
    public function canEdit(Request $request)
    {
        $canEdit = Permission::canEdit(
            $request->user(), 
            $request->siteModel
        );

        $statusCode = ($canEdit) ? 200 : 403;

        return Response()
            ->json([
                'can-edit' => $canEdit
            ], $statusCode);
    }
```

Really looking forward for some comments / suggestions.

Comment: I don't see much to review here.  Outside of declaring `$payload['can-edit'] = ...` and removing the parentheses from `$statusCode`, I don't think there is anything to change. I mean, even `$payload['can-edit']` is a subject decision to declutter the `->json()` parameters -- which I probably wouldn't do personally.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with mickmackusa that your code is pretty good overall. If you wanted to condense it, you can refactor to something like below:

```php
public function canEdit(Request $request) {
  $canEdit = Permission::canEdit($request->user(), $request->siteModel);

  return response()->json(['can-edit' => $canEdit], $canEdit ? 200 : 403);
}
```

- Placing the opening brace on the same line as your `canEdit()` definition can help condense, but if you use a newline, keep it consistent
- Both the `$canEdit = ...;` definition and `return response()->json(..);` statements are under the recommended 80 characters line length, so removing the line breaks is fine
- The definition of `$statusCode` can be removed in favour of an in-line ternary as the 2nd parameter to your `json()` method, as defining a variable for a single use is unnecessary
- You can add or remove a line-break between your two statements, I prefer an empty line before `return`, but depends on your configuration/consistency